# "ArrayList" no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para geração de relatórios de certificações de fibras ópticas, e tais relatórios são elaborados por meio da importação de arquivos XML e TXT. A questão é a seguinte:

Uma certificação é feita dentro de um "Trecho", que têm os seguintes atributos: (`Localidade_A`, `Localidade_B`, distância, `Dio_A`, `Dio_B`, `Fibras_A`, `Fibras_B`, entre outras).

Meu problema está justamente nessas `Fibras_A` e `Fibras_B`, porque um trecho tem 'x' `Fibras_A` e 'y' `Fibras_B`, onde 'x' e 'y' são passados na hora da criação do Trecho. Não estou conseguindo, ou melhor, não estou entendendo como criar essas `ArrayLists` para `Fibras_A` e `Fibras_B`, na classe `Trecho`, a depender do valor passado na hora da criação.

Eu tenho a classe `Trecho`, que tem os seguintes atributos:

```
class Trecho(models.Model):

    rede = models.CharField("Rede*", max_length = 50, blank = False, choices = rede_choices)
    localidade_A = models.ForeignKey(Localidade, related_name = 'localA', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    localidade_B = models.ForeignKey(Localidade, related_name = 'localB', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dio_A = models.CharField("Dio", max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True)
    dio_B = models.CharField("Dio", max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True)
    distancia = models.CharField("Distância de A para B (m)*", max_length = 9, blank = False, null = True)
```

E uma classe `Fibra`, que deve ter os seguintes atributos:

```
class Fibra(models.Model):

    id_fibra =
    distancia =
    subtrecho =
    statusFibra =
```

Uma print da tela para vocês entenderem. Quando eu clicar em `salvar` o sistema deve criar 24 `fibras_A` e 36 `fibras_B`.

[image: print]

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma chave estrangeira da sua classe Fibra para Trecho e uma nova coluna para indicar o tipo dessa fibra, se é A ou B

```
 TIPOA = 'A'
    TIPOB = 'B'
    TIPO_FIBRA_CHOICES = (
        (TIPOA, 'Tipo A'),
        (TIPOB, 'Tipo B'),
    )
    class Trecho(models.Model):
        ...
        def obter_fibras_tipoA(self):
            return self.fibra_trecho.filter(tipo_fibra=TIPOA)

        def obter_fibras_tipoB(self):
            return self.fibra_trecho.filter(tipo_fibra=TIPOB)

        def obter_todas fibras(self):
            return self.fibra_trecho.all()

    class Fibra(models.Model):
        ...
        tipo_fibra = models.CharField(choices=TIPO_FIBRA_CHOICES)
        trecho = models.ForeignKey(Trecho, related_name="fibra_trecho")
```

Agora que temos ja a ligação entre as 2 tabelas e as funções para obter os dados de formas juntas ou separadas so resta configurar a criação

```
  Fibra.objects.create(tipo_fibra=TIPOA, ...) # ... significa o resto dos atributos
  Fibra.objects.create(tipo_fibra=TIPOB, ...)
```

é so criar cada fibra passando seu tipo e o resto dos seus atributos, agora a logica de criação para diferenciar 1 fibra da outra pra simplesmente não criar 34 objetos exatamente iguais, ai depende de você e da como você quer fazer isso

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, vou tentar fazer aqui.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado meu amigo, salvou meu dia